# Linux Find RAM type as a non-root User

Tags: memory, non-root-user, ram

I have found the following command to work the best for memory determining the type of RAM installed:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep DDR
```

But the thing is, I don't want to use the sudo command, therefore I am trying to find a command that can be used used by a normal user.

I do not want to download anything.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't do this.

You likely need to use `sudo` because you don't have execute permissions on the file.  You can verify this with: `ls -l $(which dmidecode)`.  In order to give yourself execute permissions on the file you can do:  `sudo chmod +x $(which dmidecode)`

Comment: Why should i not do this? Are there some privacy concern with checking the Memory Type?

Comment: Because there is a reason `/sbin` exists, and a reason why your user doesn't have access to it.  There is a reason `sudo` exists and there is a reason why all users don't have root access.  Why not use sudo is a more appropriate question.